# firebase Firestore document read

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am using google cloud FireStore as a database for our e-commerce mobile application. I am a bit confused about the document read count for firestore documents when we retrieve documents from cloud firestore.

Location of firebase doc: users/123/
This doc contains users information like userId, userName, wishlist, cart, addresses and so.
I have used multiple sub-maps to save all user data in a single document to reduce firestore billing costs.
Structure of document :

```
userId:"123",
userName:"Sunil",
addresses : {
  address1 : {
    "doorNo":"123",
    "city" : "Bengaluru"
  },
  address2 : {
    "doorNo":"456",
    "city" : "Bengaluru"
  },
  address3 : {
    "doorNo":"789",
    "city" : "Bengaluru"
  },
wishlistItems:{
  item1 : {
    "itemId":"1"
  },
  item2 : {
    "itemId":"2"
  },
  item3 : {
    "itemId":"3"
  },
  item4 : {
    "itemId":"4"
  },
 },
cartItems:{
  cartItem1:{
    "itemId":"1",
    "itemCount":"2",
  },
  cartItem2:{
    "itemId":"2",
    "itemCount":"5",
  },
  cartItem3:{
    "itemId":"3",
    "itemCount":"7",
  },
  cartItem1:{
    "itemId":"4",
    "itemCount":"8",
  },
 },
},
```

I retrieve the document as follow:
firestore().collection("users").doc("123").get();

My Questions :
how many reads will be counted for each retrieval?
Will it be only one as I am retrieving only a single document or will it be 12 (as the document is having 11 sub-maps and 1 as normal count)?

Please, help me get clear on this. Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are reading everything from a single document, it counts as 1 read.

Comment: First, I wanna thank you for making time to reply to this. Your reply was really helped me to understand billing criteria correctly.

Comment: my another question is, how many key-value pairs can we add in a single document. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Reads are charged on how many *documents* you get back in the result *irrespective* of content.

```
firestore().collection("users").doc("123").get();
```

The above read will cost only 1 read (that too if the document exists).

```
firestore().collection("users").where("age", ">=", 10).get();
```

For example, in above query if 57 docs are matched and returned then you'll be charged 57 reads.

---

If you have offline persistence enabled and some docs are read from cache, you won't be charged for them.

Comment: First, I wanna thank you for making time to reply to this. Your reply was really helpful to me, I hope it will be helpful for others as well to get a clear idea about firestore billing costs.

Comment: @I'mSunil3 you're welcome. And there's no limit on how many key value pairs you can add in a doc as long as the total size is below 1 MB

Comment: @Dharmaraj If the OP has offline persistence enabled, which is by default in Cloud Firestore, then he will be able to read the cache only while offline. When the OP has internet connectivity, it will always read the online version of the documents.